# Nagios: are certificates required for SSL/TLS?

Tags: ssl, certificates, nagios, nrpe

Configuring check_nrpe and NRPE daemon with --enable-ssl generates a DH key pair. Are these DH keys enough to establish SSL connection? Or do we need certs and keys signed by a CA? Docs say certificates CAN be used for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL/TLS can support sessions that do not require X.509 certificates, such as anonymous Diffie Hellman, but it's very unlikely that you'll come across real world implementations that use it - for a start there is no authentication with this cipher suite.

There is [documentation here](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-configuring-ssl-tls.html) that describes the process needed to configure TLS in Nagios.  The *Terminology* section has:

> To implement SSL you need to generate a certificate. When you generate
>   a certificate, you create a request that needs to be signed by a
>   Certificate Authority (CA). This CA can be:
>
> - A trusted company like VeriSign
> - An internal CA that is part of your IT infrastructure, like a Microsoft Windows CA
> - The Nagios Core server itself (self signed)

Therefore, depending on the level of security/convenience you need, you might get away with a simple self-signed certificate.

Comment: so with anon DH, there is encryption but no authentication?

Comment: Correct - DH will be used to generate a symmetric key for encryption, but neither end will know with who they're sharing encrypted information. That's why it's never used.